# Selecting wrong td.class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to get a alert with spefic infos of a dynamic loading table..
thats the code i already have

```
$('#notizenTable tr.notizenTableRow').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this).data({ position: $(this).index() }),
    $input = $this.find('input');
    $anlage = $this.find('td.stmAnlagedaten');
    $input.bind('change', function () {
        alert($anlage.html());
        cb = $(this);
        cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
        alert("Hauptnotiz;" + $(this).val() + ";" + $anlage.html());

    })

})
```

Html:

```
    <tr class="notizenTableRow" data-counter="<!$MG_NotizID>">
            <td class="shrink tdcenter"><input type="checkbox" class="stmStickyNotizen" id="chkboxStickyNotizen" style="margin-left:3px;" value="false" data-chkboxselector="<!$MG_NotizID>"/></td>
            <td class="shrink stmAnlagedaten"><!$MG_AnlageDatum>&nbsp;<!$MG_AnlageZeit>&nbsp;&nbsp;<!$MG_AnlSachbearbeiter> <!$MG_AenSachbearbeiter></td>
            <td class="shrink"><!$MG_VorgangsartBez></td>
            <!-- style="width: 20%;" -->
            <td class="shrink"><!$MG_Thema></td>
            <td class="expandNotizen"><!$MG_Notiz></td>
            <td class="hiddenTableColumn" id="stmNotizenStatus"><!$MG_Status></td>
            <td class="hiddenTableColumn"></td>
    </tr>
```

So now my problem in detail, with my JS i get the right infos about the $input (i know it because of alert), but it finds the wrong td with the class of stmAnlagedaten, can some one explain me why? Am i searching on the wrong way?

Comment: What is the actual output from  $anlage.html() within your alert? (It can be easier to copy the text if you use console.log rather than alert)

Comment: i cant check the console right now, tommorow i could.
the output of $anlage.html() is the last or first generated (i dont know the order of the generation right now) row of <td class="shrink stmAnlagedaten"><!$MG_AnlageDatum>&nbsp;<!$MG_AnlageZeit>&nbsp;&nbsp;<!$MG_AnlSachbearbeiter> <!$MG_AenSachbearbeiter></td>
            <td class="shrink"><!$MG_VorgangsartBez></td>

Comment: i found my mistake... i had a ";" instead of a "," after my $input = $this.find('input'); ..... what ever

Comment: Ahh interesting. If you would like to catch that same type of error in the future more easily, you can use "use strict"; which will throw an error if you try to set a variable without a var statement. Then you can go straight to the problem.

Comment: cool, didnt knew about that, thx for the info! :)